# How to whitelist an nginx ingress custom port

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have an nginx ingress in Kubernetes with both a whitelist (handled by a `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range` annotation) and also a custom port mapping (which exposes an SFTP server port 22 via a `--tcp-services-configmap` configmap).  The whitelist works great for 80 and 443, but it does not work for 22.  How do I whitelist my custom port?

Configuration looks roughly like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  ...
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.33.0
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
            - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
            - --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx
            - --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
            - name: sftp
              containerPort: 22
        ...

kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .controllerName }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: {{ .ipAllowList }}

kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
data:
  22: "default/sftp:22"
```

UPDATE

Thanks to @jordanm I discovered that I can restrict IP addresses for all ports via `loadBalancerSourceRanges` in the LoadBalancer rather than nginx:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: {{ .loadBalancerIp }}
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https
    - name: sftp
      port: 22
      targetPort: sftp
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
    {{ .ipAllowList }}
```

Comment: Do you have a load balancer in front of your ingress? Does the load balancer support non-http protocols?

Comment: @jordanm: Yes, got a load balancer service in front.  Is there a better way to set up an allow list with that?

Comment: Does the load balancer support tcp services or is it http(s) only?

Comment: @jordanm I expose the ports I need: 80, 443, and 22.  With your help I discovered the `loadBalancerSourceRanges` setting, and while that didn't answer my exact question it solved my problem, so thank you!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Happy I was of some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly take a look at this issue: [ip-whitelist-support](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3202&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1617960974480000&usg=AFQjCNFEc_ZuZIZTwjqrhYMpnDtt1mztAg).

> IPs are not whitelisted for TCP services, an alternative would be to create a separate firewall for the TCP services and whitelist the IPs at the firewall level.

For specific location [{{ $path }}](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/1b9a9e0fc4e17d88433f5b52f390f15e570c7287/rootfs/etc/nginx/template/nginx.tmpl%23L1085&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1617960974480000&usg=AFQjCNGaXNDfqS-uNt2_betPyIk3Kd2sQQ)  we have defined
[{{ if isLocationAllowed $location }}](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/1b9a9e0fc4e17d88433f5b52f390f15e570c7287/rootfs/etc/nginx/template/nginx.tmpl%23L1163&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1617960974480000&usg=AFQjCNGYgDKWUoRSzovTgcbBG2VIbpXwDA).

Check official Ingress documentation: [ingress-kubernetes](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/%23what-is-ingress&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1617960974480000&usg=AFQjCNFnS5b7LtmtJ5KN8HIFFshHOB8MLQ).

> Ingress exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to services within the cluster. Traffic routing is controlled by rules  defined on the Ingress resource.
>
> An Ingress does not expose arbitrary ports or protocols. Exposing services other than HTTP and HTTPS to the internet typically uses a service of type Service.Type=NodePort or Service.Type=LoadBalancer.
>
> You must have an Ingress controller to satisfy an Ingress. Only
> creating an Ingress resource has no effect.

In this case Ingress resource instrument ingress-controller how to deal with http/https requests. In this approach nginx-ingress controller as a software (introduce layer-7 functionality/loadbalancing).

If you are interested with nginx ingress tcp support:

> Ingress does not support TCP or UDP services. For this reason this  Ingress controller uses the flags --tcp-services-configmap and  --udp-services-configmap

See: [exposing-tcp-udp-services](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/%23exposing-tcp-and-udp-services&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1617960974480000&usg=AFQjCNFUyG9Q0xncME9RAqvfoQOPA4nNag)

If you want to check more granular configuration while working with your tcp service you should consider using L4 loadbalancing/firewall settings provided by your cloud provider.

Comment: FYI I don't consider this an actual answer to my question, which is why I posted my response in the question.  It does solve my problem, because I happened to be using a load balancer, but it doesn't answer the question of how to whitelist an nginx ingress custom port

Comment: I have edited my answer, please take a look.